# Redirect if requirement is not satisfied

Tags: php, symfony

I have many controller actions that require some context in the session so they can be executed.

```
/**
 * @Route("/some/route", name="some_route")
 */
public function oneOfMyAction(Request $request)
{
    if (!$request->getSession()->get('some_required_variable')) {
        $this->redirectToRoute('some_other_route');
    }

    return $this->render('AppBundle::protected-content.html.twig');
}
```

Is there a way to factorize this requirement in an annotation or something so I can easily use it in my controllers ?

```
/**
 * @Route("/some/route", name="some_route")
 * @SomeRequiredVariable()
 */
public function oneOfMyAction(Request $request)
{
    return $this->render('AppBundle::protected-content.html.twig');
}
```

If I can implement a `SomeRequiredVariable` class, how would I do it ?
Or would there be another know way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've always found the documentation on custom annotations a bit lacking. But hopefully the following will help you.

**Prerequisites**:

- You need a class annotated as `@Annotation`. This will act as a *container* for all the parameters used with the annotion.
- You need an appropriate event listener which finds and reads the annotation and acts accordinglingly.

---

## The annotation class

For this to work, you need to define all properties, which can be used for your custom annotation (here `route, route_params, required`), as class properties.

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Annotation/RedirectOnMissing.php
namespace AppBundle\Annotation;

use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class RedirectOnMissing
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $route;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $route_params = [];

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $required = [];

    /**
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function __construct(array $options)
    {
        $options = $this->configureOptions(new OptionsResolver())->resolve($options);

        $this->route = $options['route'];
        $this->route_params = $options['route_params'];
        $this->required = $options['required'];
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     *
     * @return OptionsResolver
     */
    private function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        return $resolver
            ->setRequired(['route', 'required'])
            ->setDefaults([
                'route_params' => []
            ])
            ->setAllowedTypes('route', 'string')
            ->setAllowedTypes('required', 'array')
            ->setAllowedTypes('route_params', 'array')
        ;
    }

    /**
     * Get `route`
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRoute()
    {
        return $this->route;
    }

    /**
     * Get `route_params`
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getRouteParams()
    {
        return $this->route_params;
    }

    /**
     * Get `required`
     *
     * @return string[]
     */
    public function getRequired()
    {
        return $this->required;
    }
}
```

## The listener

You need to listen to the `kernel.controller` event, for otherwise you won't have access to the *active* controller.

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/EventListener/FilterControllerListener.php
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use AppBundle\Annotation\RedirectOnMissing;
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\Reader;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation as Http;

class FilterControllerListener
{
    /**
     * @var Reader
     */
    private $reader;

    /**
     * @var UrlGeneratorInterface
     */
    private $urlGenerator;

    /**
     * @var SessionInterface
     */
    private $session;

    /**
     * @param Reader                $reader
     * @param UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator
     * @param SessionInterface      $session
     */
    public function __construct(Reader $reader, UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator, SessionInterface $session)
    {
        $this->reader = $reader;
        $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    /**
     * @param FilterControllerEvent $event
     */
    public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
    {
        $controller = $event->getController();
        if (!is_array($controller)) {
            return;
        }

        /** @var $methodAnnotation RedirectOnMissing */
        $methodAnnotation = $this->reader->getMethodAnnotation(
            new \ReflectionMethod($controller[0], $controller[1]),
            RedirectOnMissing::class
        );

        if (null !== $methodAnnotation) {
            foreach ($methodAnnotation->getRequired() as $key) {
                if (!$this->session->has($key)) {
                    $event->setController(function () use($methodAnnotation) {
                        return new Http\RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate($methodAnnotation->getRoute(), $methodAnnotation->getRouteParams()));
                    });
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## The configuration

```
// src/AppBundle/Resources/config/services.yml

services:
    // ...

    app.event_listner.controller_listener:
        class: AppBundle\EventListener\FilterControllerListener
        arguments:
            - "@annotation_reader"
            - "@router"
            - "@session"
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller, method: onKernelController }
```

## Usage

```
<?php

/**
 * @Cfg\Route("/test")
 *
 * @RedirectOnMissing(route="home", required={"foo", "bar"})
 */
public function testAction()
{
    return new Http\Response('no redirect');
}
```

---

*Note: When dealing with custom annotations, it might be that you need to clear the cache often to see changes.*

Comment: Wow ! You should submit a PR with this answer as new cookbook :) Thank you for this quality answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own annotations and put your logic into `kernel.request` event listener.

Annotation functionality does not become to Symfony, it comes from Doctrine. For first need to add new annotation's class at your bundle

```
<?php

namespace Acme\Bundle\TestBundle\Annotation;

/**
 * @Annotation
 * @Target({"METHOD"})
 */
class Custom
{
}
```

The second part is a creating a subscriber with your logic.

```
<?php

namespace Acme\Bundle\TestBundle\EventListener;

use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\Reader;
use Acme\Bundle\TestBundle\Annotations\Custom;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class CustomEventSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    protected $reader;

    public function __construct(Reader $reader)
    {
        $this->reader = $reader;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::CONTROLLER => 'onKernelController',
        ];
    }

    public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
    {
        if (!is_array($controller = $event->getController())) {
            return;
        }

        $method = new \ReflectionMethod($controller[0], $controller[1]);
        foreach ($this->reader->getMethodAnnotations($method) as $annotation) {
            if ($annotation instanceof Custom) {
               // put your logic here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you have to define subscriber as a service.

```
services:
    custom_subscriber:
        class: Acme\Bundle\TestBundle\EventListener\CustomEventSubscriber
        arguments: [@annotation_reader]
        tags:
            - {name: kernel.event_subscriber}
```

After that you can mark controller's action with your annotation.

For more information see [here](https://gist.github.com/cystbear/1391850).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes, resulting in your answer being useless and consequently deleted.

Comment: I was actually on this link trying to understand how I could do what I'm searching for with it. Though I don't really get how `Permission` is linked to the `AnnotationDriver` in the example.

Comment: I have modified my comment. Doctrine annotation driver parse annotations and map annotation from method/class to correct class which describe annotation